How to call this part, plate with studs on the bottom? Could you help me find it on bricklink?
I have similar part like that, but black and with holes in the stud. Double sided. I don't know in which set it came from. Could you help me find it in some catalog?


COBI makes parts like the o.p.'s description
https://shop.leggodt.nl/product/cobi-plate-2-x-2-modified-with-studs-on-both-sides-black/


3D printed, not LEGO
If you go to https://www.stlfinder.com/model/lego-double-plate-2x2-nGqPKQAN/2784932/ you will find that this is a part that can be 3D printed.  Your picture is very similar to the one found there.


Here is a 2x2 lego plate that fits perfectly with the real legos. This piece does not exist among the real lego, but is however strongly useful, this is why I decided to remedy this lack, thus offering a new infinity of possibilities. The first uses can be relatively "hard" due to slight printing defects, but they will disappear with wear.

Meta

I found the page for this 3d printed part using Google Lens for image search.
Even the background and part shading in the pictures is identical.


I have an original part like that. Maybe it comes from technics, I don't know. I will post a real picture later.

@noisy Technic has different connection system. The piece you got is for clone brand.

@noisy Please post a clear photo of the part.
